# How to change htaccess rules to make urls better for seo?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am experiencing some problems changing URLs with `.htaccess`.

I can change the rule for `index.php` but I can not change for any other page on my website.

Working example: `http://example.com/novo_website/index.php` - I successfully change the rule to `http://example.com/novo_website/inicio/`.

Non working example: `http://example.com/novo_website/pedido_orcamento.php` the rewrite rule is not working to `http://example.com/novo_website/orcamento/`.

The last example gives 404 error. Also, the 404 page redirection does not work also.

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /novo_website/

ErrorDocument 404 /novo_website/404_not_found.html


RewriteRule ^orcamento/?$ pedido_orcamento.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^registo/?$ registo.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^entrar/?$ area_empresa.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^inicio/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Can anyone help me resolve this situation?

Comment: Is there also a physical subdirectory called `/orcamento`? Otherwise, there doesn't appear to be any reason (from what you've posted) why this would not work. What do you mean exactly by "not working"? Do you get a 404? What is the exact URL you are requesting?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't have a subdirectory call orcamento. I just have several php files, like index.php, pedido_orcamento.php, registo.php, etc. With the above rules i can call inicio and show the index.php but if call orcamento it shows a generic 404 error.

Comment: That would seem to imply that `/novo_website/pedido_orcamento.php` does not exist? If you request `/novo_website/pedido_orcamento.php` directly does it work? Where is your `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: If I request `/novo_website/pedido_orcamento.php` directly it works correctly. My .htaccess file is located on `/novo_website/` directory.

Comment: "it shows a generic 404 error" - is that your `404-not-found.html` page or some other Apache default? Do you have any `.htaccess` files in parent directories?